# How to manipulate modifiers in annotation macros

Tags: scala, annotations, scala-macros

How to manipulate modifiers? 
For example, I want to exclude `Flaga.CASE` in `ClassDef` modifiers.
However, following causes a compile error.

```scala
case q"$mods class $name [..$tp](..$vals) extends ..$exts { ..$defs }" if mods.hasFlag(Flag.CASE) =>
       val m = mods - Flag.CASE
       q"$m class $name [..$tp](..$vals) { ..$defs }"
```

error is

```
[error] ...: value - is not a member of c.universe.Modifiers
[error]         val m = mods - Flag.CASE
[error]                      ^
[error] one error found
```

Ok, Modifiers api does not have `-` to exclude specified element (I expected this method works like Set's `-` if exists).

My question is, as I mentioned above, is there a method to manipulate Modifiers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
import c.universe._

implicit class ModifiersOps(left: Modifiers) {
  def & (right: FlagSet): Modifiers = left match {
    case Modifiers(flags, privateWithin, annots) => Modifiers(flags & right, privateWithin, annots)
  }
}

implicit class FlagSetOps(left: FlagSet) {
  def & (right: FlagSet): FlagSet = (left.asInstanceOf[Long] & right.asInstanceOf[Long]).asInstanceOf[FlagSet]
  def unary_~ : FlagSet = (~ left.asInstanceOf[Long]).asInstanceOf[FlagSet]
}

annottees.head match {
  case q"${mods: Modifiers} class $name [..$tp](..$vals) extends ..$exts { ..$defs }" if mods.hasFlag(Flag.CASE) =>
    val m = mods & ~Flag.CASE
    q"$m class $name [..$tp](..$vals) { ..$defs }"
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay in my response. I found an api that allows me to manipulate modifiers in `ModifiersApi`, `mapAnnotations`. This api use lambda that can manipulate Modifier.  However, your `ModifierOps` feels me that Modifiers do not have only Modifier like `Flag.CASE`. So, I don't know the better way to manipulate modifiers.

Comment: @BitMaPT `mapAnnotations` can change `annots` in `Modifiers(flags, privateWithin, annots)`. If you want to change `flags` you can deconstruct-construct `Modifiers` or use my extension methods.